# Simple log-file for a PS script?

Tags: powershell

I have a PS script that deletes specific files from a folder. But I would like a log-file to be created and updated when the script runs that lists which files have been removed.

My script:

```
$Directory = "C:\test"
Get-ChildItem -path $Directory | 
Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-45) } | 
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: Look at Start-Transcript / Stop-Transcript

Comment: If you add -verbose to your commands, you'll get  more detail also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup simple logging with Set-Content and Update-Content. Then modify your script to do both tasks.

```
$Directory = "C:\test"
$files = Get-ChildItem -path $Directory | 
    where-object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-45) } | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
foreach($file in $files){
    Add-Content -Path C:\test\log.log -Value "Deleted file: $file"
    Remove-Item -path $file -Recurse -Force -Confirm:$false
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have meaningful and easy to write and read logs in your application, I advise you to use the `EventLog` cmdlets available on Powershell.

Directly from Powershell help:

`get-help New-EventLog -ShowWindow`

```
Example 1: Create an event log and register its source
    PS C:\>New-EventLog -Source "TestApp" -LogName "TestLog" -MessageResourceFile "C:\Test\TestApp.dll"
```

`get-help Write-EventLog -ShowWindow`

```
Example 1: Write an event to the Application event log
    PS C:\>Write-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Source "MyApp" -EventID 3001 -EntryType Information -Message "MyApp added a user-requested feature to the display." -Category 1 -RawData 10,20
```

Then you can read your log and save it to a file if you need to.

Comment: This is for Windows event log logging, not for the purpose the OP requires which is of tracking removed files and maintaing a list of them.

Comment: It can also be used for application logging, the good side of it vs just a file adding messages is that it tracks time, entry type and other metadata in a more standard way than creating your own custom logfile in your application folder. See the following post for reference: [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-create-and-to-use-a-new-event-log/)